# Retry Post request when device is back online

Tags: android, rest, service, httprequest, alarmmanager

i have a small android app that makes some POST request to a server the problem is that i want that my app would be capable,when the request fails, of retrying the Post some time after checking the avaibility of the network on the device. How this can be done? is necessary to implement a service and a database to persist the data that i'm sending? i have read something about alarmmanager but i don't know how to implement this with my activity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont necessarily need a service running all the time. When a POST or any web request fails, you can queue it. (Store the request somehow [Shared params, db]). Then use a broadcast receiver and subscribe connectivity changed intent. In the receiver, check if you have connectivity now. If you *and* there are things in the queue, then you can spawn a service to take care of the queue.

The two exact broadcasts you should be interested are these

```
 android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED
 android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE
```

You can register to them in your manifest like this

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <!-- .... -->
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In that broadcast receiver you can use this code to see if you have a network connection.

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if(cm == null)
        return false;

    final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

for this code, you also need these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one more question, this broadcast receiver would work even if the user has left the activity?

Comment: Yes, of course. the broadcast receiver will get notified irrespective of whether your activity is running or not.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which extends BroadcastReceiver and than register that class like this:
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiverExtension, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

Any changes on network will trigger this broadcast.

You can check on intent extras ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO,  ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO, ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY and ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON for more information about the received changes.